Prisma openssl version issue
I’m encountering an issue while trying to compose Docker instances in my local environment. When I run the docker-compose up command, I get the following error:
> 2024-12-10 12:46:12 > laredo-backend-api@0.0.1 start:docker:dev
> 2024-12-10 12:46:12 > npm install && npm run start:prisma && npm run
> start:dev 2024-12-10 12:46:12  2024-12-10 12:46:16  2024-12-10
> 12:46:16 added 1 package, and audited 1011 packages in 3s 2024-12-10
> 12:46:16  2024-12-10 12:46:16 134 packages are looking for funding
> 2024-12-10 12:46:16   run `npm fund` for details 2024-12-10 12:46:16 
> 2024-12-10 12:46:16 6 vulnerabilities (1 low, 2 moderate, 3 high)
> 2024-12-10 12:46:16  2024-12-10 12:46:16 To address issues that do not
> require attention, run: 2024-12-10 12:46:16   npm audit fix 2024-12-10
> 12:46:16  2024-12-10 12:46:16 To address all issues, run: 2024-12-10
> 12:46:16   npm audit fix --force 2024-12-10 12:46:16  2024-12-10
> 12:46:16 Run `npm audit` for details. 2024-12-10 12:46:16  2024-12-10
> 12:46:16 > laredo-backend-api@0.0.1 start:prisma 2024-12-10 12:46:16 >
> prisma migrate deploy 2024-12-10 12:46:16  2024-12-10 12:46:22
> Environment variables loaded from .env 2024-12-10 12:46:22 Prisma
> schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma 2024-12-10 12:46:22 Datasource
> "db": PostgreSQL database "laredo", schema "public" at "postgres:5432"
> 2024-12-10 12:46:22  2024-12-10 12:46:17 prisma:warn Prisma failed to
> detect the libssl/openssl version to use, and may not work as
> expected. Defaulting to "openssl-1.1.x". 2024-12-10 12:46:17 Please
> manually install OpenSSL and try installing Prisma again. 2024-12-10
> 12:46:22 prisma:warn Prisma failed to detect the libssl/openssl
> version to use, and may not work as expected. Defaulting to
> "openssl-1.1.x". 2024-12-10 12:46:22 Please manually install OpenSSL
> and try installing Prisma again. 2024-12-10 12:46:22 Error: Could not
> parse schema engine response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'E',
> "Error load"... is not valid JSON 2024-12-10 12:46:22 npm notice
> 2024-12-10 12:46:22 npm notice New minor version of npm available!
> 10.8.2 -> 10.9.2 2024-12-10 12:46:22 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.2 2024-12-10 12:46:22
> npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.9.2 2024-12-10
> 12:46:22 npm notice

I've done some googling and ran the following commands in order to fix this:

brew install openssl@3

rm -rf node_modules && npm i

npx prisma generate

npx prisma migrate --dev


The follwoing is my prisma generator
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "linux-musl", "darwin-arm64", "linux-musl-openssl-3.0.x"]
}

Docker file
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder

USER root

RUN npm i -g npm@~9.3.1

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . ./

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

RUN npm ci

RUN npm run build

FROM node:20-alpine AS deployment

# added this to try to fix but still broken

RUN set -ex; \
    apk update; \
    apk add --no-cache \
    openssl

COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /usr/app /usr/app

USER node

CMD ["sh"]

Any pointers are appreciated thanks!

Hey , I have the same problem . everything was ok in my project, but suddenly I saw this error and my backend has stoped working

@MoeinMoeinnia if you figure it out please let me know

Thanks for all the pointers everyone the thing that ended up working however was adding FROM node:20-alpine3.17 to the docker and docker compose files. As shown in this comment https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/2175#issuecomment-2530559047

Add this to your DockerFile, this works for me!
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache openssl


I added this to my docker file and ran docker compose up --build yet I got the same error

was there any other commands you ran to get this to work once making those changes?

I just removed all images and cache from pnpm and rebuilt the containers.

Try reading this issue: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/2175#issuecomment-2530130523

This issue is solved with https://github.com/prisma/prisma/pull/25824 and will be available in prisma 6.1.0.

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libssl.so.3 /lib/libssl.so.3
https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/2175#issuecomment-2530130523

I tried installing openssl manually in Dockerfile and changing my base image to slim os, it fixed my problem :


FROM node:20-slim

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl




FROM node:20-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache openssl

install openssl to your dockerfile cuz in alpine image will miss some lib or package, in this case alpine miss openssl so prsima can detech
